# formal argument "ylab" matched by multiple actual arguments

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to add a label to my Y axis. But I don't know how to handle it in this case.

```
inter <- interactionMeans(m2)
inter
plot(inter, traces=c("Sentence", "DV"), ylab="Probability of approval")
```

I'm getting the error

```
 formal argument "ylab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

[plot without "ylab=..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elxwv.png)

```
require(lme4)
library(phia)
require(tables)

m2 <- glmer(value ~ Sentence + DV + (Sentence * DV | lfdn) + (Sentence *  DV | le_nr), data = dw_1,
        family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun=1e8)))

inter <- interactionMeans(m2)
inter
plot(inter, traces=c("Sentence", "DV"), ylab="Probability of approval")
```

Error:

```
Fehler in matplot(means, type = type, pch = pch, axes = FALSE, xlab = "",  : 
  formales Argument "ylab" passt zu mehreren gegebenen Argumenten
```

Comment: Thanks for including code,  but it is not enough for us to help. What package is `interactionMeans` in?  What is the variable `m2`?  We cannot run your code right now. If you cannot show us m2, is there a small example that you can show?

Comment: It the title of your question the error you are getting when you run the code? It woudl be more helpful if you titled the question with a summary of the problem you are having and then add the error output to your question. Thanks!

Comment: @d.b: Do you mean like this? `names(attributes(inter)[[1]]$dim) = "Probability of approval"` `plot(inter, traces=c("Sentence", "DV")` this didn't work

Comment: The problem stems from the fact that fact that the package itself is setting `ylab = ...` during the plotting phase. The only real method for fixing such an issue is either overwriting the `plot` method for `interactionMeans` objects or figure how it names the `ylab`, and overwrite this value if possible. More often than not the implementation simply does not have this option. (Even Fox, J.'s `car` package does not have this feature in many of his plots!)

Comment: Thanks for improving your question   +1

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get the error is that `plot.interactionMeans()` doesn't include a `ylab` argument. This is understandable, as the y-labels are just the names of the IVs in the original model, if you wanted to change their names, you'd do it there. If you however want to add a title at the lower margin, below the y-axis labels, which appears to be what you want, then you can do that quite easily with `mtext()`. What's far more frustrating than the missing `ylab` is that they hard-code the plotting margins (`par(c("mar", "oma"))`), so there's little to do about the tight space.

```
library(phia)

data(Adler)
mod.adler <- lm(rating ~ instruction * expectation, data=Adler)
means.adler <- interactionMeans(mod.adler)

plot(means.adler, abbrev.levels=TRUE)
mtext("Experimenter pre-conditioning", 1, at=par("usr")[1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check-in your syntax, if you have "ylab" argument listed twice.

I had a similar error when I accidentally copy-pasted the quoted argument twice in the model statement. I hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).